# How to execute code only after child form is closed? C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some code on button click which would open pop up window and some code on the same button click which I would like to run only after pop up window is closed.

Here is an example.

```
private void SomeButton_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            var assignCategory = new AssignCategory();
            assignCategory.Show();

        /// Some code to run only after assignCategory pop up is closed.
        }
```

I can not run `/// some code` on `private void AssignCategory_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)` because the code will only run if the `SomeButton` is clicked.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `ShowDialog` instead of `Show` or subscribe to the `Closed` event of `assignCategory`.

Comment: Use `assignCategory.ShowDialog();` to make ik blocking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `Form.Show()` will return once the child form is shown, not hold the execution until the childform has closed. Alternatively you can use `Form.ShowDialog()` to halt execution until the form has closed.

You need to subscribe to the `Form.Closed` event of the childform, and take action upon it firing if you want to run the two Form asynchronous.

To run the code only after a the OK-button was pressed you have to declare a `EventHandler` in your childform like so:

```
public event EventHandler OnOkClick;
```

Then trigger the event at the bottom or a certain point in your Button:

```
OnOkClick();
```

In your main Form contructor you then simply subscribe to that event

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. And how can I run the code only after user clicks OK button on child form? For example, ```public void AssignCateg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }``` running the code only after this is executed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much :)